# C++ index into string map without allocation

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

I'm writing an application with a high performance thread that doesn't allow allocation. I have a map that looks like this:

```
map<String, MyCustomClass> objectCollection;
```

Where String is a custom wrapper around std::string. I want to be able to write code like this on the high priority thread:

```
int someValue = objectCollection["some string"].value;
```

When I do this, indexing into the array causes the construction of a String, which requires allocation. My thought was that I might be able to define a custom comparator for my map that would accept a const char*, and be able to do string comparison with a String's c string guts. Is this possible? How might it look?

I can do something like this with String instances:

```
String strTest = "";
const char* chars = strTest.chars();
```

Comment: Will "some string" always be a constant or can it be any `const char*`?

Comment: If you need speed, have you considered `std::unordered_map` ?

Comment: @Nate Kohl "some string" will literally be programmed into the code. Definitely a constant.

Comment: @Borgleader how would that help me with this problem?

Comment: @ZECTBynmo How about @TheBuzzSaw's answer, but declare the `static const string` as a global variable? That way, the allocation happens even before the threads are created.

Comment: @ZECTBynmo It wouldn't, that's why it's a comment. Not an answer. I'm merely suggesting it because it may help him.

Comment: static is not an option for me either unfortunately @timrau

Comment: @ZECTBynmo So, memory allocation before `main()` is prohibited, right? Then how do you construct `objectCollection`?

Comment: I can allocate at construction time, so I could just create a bunch of String instances ahead of time and refer to them symbolically, but that's not really the solution I was hoping for.

Comment: Are all the subscript strings known ahead of time?  You might look at the perfect hash function generator (gperf).

Comment: @brianbeuning yes that's how I've implemented it right now. I'm not very happy with the hash solution, but it does work.

Answer (score 3):

You can get away with doing only one allocation.

```
static const string Key("some string");
int someValue = objectCollection[Key];
```

Doing it with zero allocations would require a different string class. You would have somehow make use of `const char*` and a custom comparison mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, 0 allocations allowed. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `static const string Key("some string");`?

Comment: @ZECTBynmo: I suspect you're missing the point here... another thread or the OS loader could construct Key before the "high performance" thread starts, and the latter could repeatedly assign new text into it that won't allocate unless longer than the existing `capacity()`.  If the high-perf thread isn't extremely transient, it could take the hit of a one-off allocation at startup, knowing however-many subsequent assignment (and hence map indexing) operations will be fast.  `Key` could be made thread-specific if there are several high-perf threads.

Comment: @timrau - the two lines are practically identical, when you declare the variable and use `=` on the same line it is not assignment, the copy constructor gets called instead.

Comment: I'll change it just to be succinct.

Comment: @ZECTBynmo The map itself does allocations. Why exactly are you aiming for zero allocations? You'd have to use `find()` instead of `operator[]` to avoid creating items.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw: I think it's a given here that the key will be found... the point is avoiding allocation during the preparation of a string to use as the key during the search.

Comment: OK, but if you're allowed to do allocations in setting up the map, why can't you do allocations in setting up the one key? It'll do no allocations during your important execution.

Answer (score 3):

A custom comparison won't do you any good with a map; the lookup operator always converts its argument to the key type, regardless of how the comparison operator works. But when you want fast lookups, there's probably a better way.

Keeping things in a sorted vector and looking them up using the binary search algorithms (lower_bound() etc) is usually faster than looking them up in a map (because, among other things, a map's internal tree structure imposes a good deal of pointer chasing on each lookup). A map is much faster for insertion than a sorted vector, but when fast lookup is more important than fast insertion, the vector is usually faster, and the vector has the advantage that you can use a heterogeneous comparison function (one that takes two different argument types).

Something like this:

```
struct Element {
    std::string key;
    Thing value;
};

bool compare(const Element& lhs, const char* rhs) {
    return lhs.key < rhs;
}

using Collection = std::vector<Element>;

inline Thing lookup(const char* key, const Collection& coll) {
    // Requires coll to be already sorted
    auto i(std::lower_bound(coll.begin(), coll.end(), key, compare));
    if (i != coll.end() && i->key == key)
        return i->value;
    else
        return Thing();
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting what might be a good alternative, though you don't mention some major drawbacks - especially for threaded access, it may be important that objects in sorted vectors may be moved during further insert/erase operations, whereas existing `std::map` elements are never moved (i.e. iterators/pointers not invalidated).

Comment: Yes, the sorted vector approach is ideal for situations where you build up the array in one phase of the program, sort it, and then look things up in a separate phase, with no (or very few) insertions or deletions interleaved with the lookups. If interleaved queries and updates are common, a map or unordered_map is definitely more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

In C++14, there are some neat new features that should allow this to happen. For instance, there's a templated map::find

```
template< class K > iterator find( const K& x );
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Answer (score 1):

All you can do is change the key_type to const char* since map::find aswell as map::operator[] aswell as map::at take key_type as their argument. as such even if you pass a const char* it will construct a String before the map function is even called. So unless you make your String static you wont get away without constructing one.

Comment: Is there a way to define an alternate comparison operator that can accept alternate types?

Comment: yes http://pastebin.com/12mqXLpT this will still call the constructor though and you could even take const String& as param that also wouldnt call the String constructor problem is it gets called since find/[]/at take a String as arg

Comment: @ZECTBynmo The 3rd argument to map<> is user defined comparator.